# Camel Proxy cosumer throws NullPointerException with servicemix

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

Hi I am trying to call a route and get a response from Java.
The route get called but the consumer does not receive a valid body, its null

I am using

```
@Produce(uri = "direct:caps.lookup")
private CommonAssetReportingServicePortType capsProxy;
...
capsProxy.getSecuritiesClassifications(getSecuritiesClassificationsRequest);
```

where `CommonAssetReportingServicePortType` is the Interface from generated from a WSDL,
and `GetSecuritiesClassificationsRequest getSecuritiesClassificationsRequest` is a JAXB generated class.

The route is very simple

```
<route id="caps-lookup" errorHandlerRef="noErrorHandler">   
  <camel:from uri="direct:caps.lookup" />   
  <log message="############# CAPS PROXY #############" />     
  <camel:to uri="cars:getClassifications" />
</route>
```

and cars is an osgi bundle in the running in the same ServiceMix instance

```
<osgi:reference id="cars" interface="org.apache.camel.Component"
    filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=cars)" />
```

Could it be because the JAXB class doesn't implement Serializable or do I need to set the body explicitly in the route from the object that I pass in in the Java code.

Trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.wmf.service.commonassetreporting.impl.ClassificationPreProcessor.process(ClassificationPreProcessor.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:50)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:99)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.fabric.FabricTraceProcessor.process(FabricTraceProcessor.java:59)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:104)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:85)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   com.service.audit.CamelAuditInterceptor.aroundInvoke(CamelAuditInterceptor.java:80)[221:audit-service:1.6.9]
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor260.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.6.0_24]
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)[:1.6.0_24]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)[59:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)[59:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:56)[59:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:39)[59:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)[59:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)[54:org.springframework.aop:3.0.5.RELEASE]
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy231.aroundInvoke(Unknown Source)[:]  at
>   com.freedomoss.osgi.CamelDynamicInterceptor$Wrapper.process(CamelDynamicInterceptor.java:78)[211:camel-commons:1.6.3]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:319)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:210)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:304)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:116)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:79)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:122)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:61)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:114)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:284)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:109)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:99)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.fabric.FabricTraceProcessor.process(FabricTraceProcessor.java:59)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:304)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:116)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:79)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:104)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:85)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:48)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.bean.CamelInvocationHandler$1.call(CamelInvocationHandler.java:79)[56:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.8.0.fuse-03-06]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.6.0_24]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.6.0_24]

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you pls add the stacktrace?

Comment: Did you checkout the code of ClassificationPreProcessor.java:40 for the NPE?